# Deleting Classes in List<T> during Realm Migration

Tags: realm-list, realm-migration

For example. I have old models, like this:

```swift
class Foo:Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ObjectId.generate()
    let bars = List<Bar>()
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Bar:Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ObjectId.generate()
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

and the new models:

```swift
class Foo:Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ObjectId.generate()
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

migration code:

```swift
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: {migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
            migration.deleteData(forType: "Bar")
        }
    })
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

When running, the error shows "Table is target of cross-table link columns".

If I ran first

```swift
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: {migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {

        }
    })
```

and then ran

```swift
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 2,
    migrationBlock: {migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {

        }
        
        if oldSchemaVersion < 2 {
            migration.deleteData(forType: "Bar")
        }
    })
```

The result worked.

Here is the question, is that a way to merge the two times migrations into one migration?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just apply the two migrations together.

```swift
let url = Realm.Configuration().fileURL!
let schemaVersion = try! schemaVersionAtURL(url)

if schemaVersion == 0 {
    autoreleasepool {
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
            // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
            // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
            schemaVersion: 1,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    
                }
        })
        _ = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
    }
    
    autoreleasepool {
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
            // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
            // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
            schemaVersion: 2,
            migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                    
                }
                
                if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                    migration.deleteData(forType: "Bar")
                }
        })
        _ = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
    }
} else {
    let configuration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: schemaVersion)
    _ = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
}
```

The `autoreleasepool` parts are necessary. Or schemaVersion 2 won't be applied.